# Detect if Google Chrome block Java plug-in

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applet, browser-plugin

The Google Chrome block Java plugin until you explicitly allow it to run. https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1247383&hl=en-US

How can I detect in javascript if Chrome block it?

Comment: Does Chrome honor the `alt` attribute of the `applet` element or the alternative HTML?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not using `applet` tag, I use `object` tag to embed applet on the page.

Comment: O..K.  Well, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only Chrome employing click-to-play features - Firefox (Java made click-to-play via blocklist), Opera (their Turbo mode makes all plugins click-to-play), ... and there are also Add-ons/Extensions that prevent plugins from running automatically.

None of those allow you do find out about plugins being click-to-play from content scripts. So ideally you address the problem in a more general way.

You can differentiate between the plugin not being installed (see `navigator.plugins`) and other cases by either

- regularly testing it's scriptability or
- having the plugin call into the pages script when it is loaded

... and assume *"failed to load or got blocked"* based on that. There is a [best-practices page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Site_Author_Guide_for_Click-To-Activate_Plugins) on MDN for this.

That distinction should usually be good enough, check e.g. how SoundCloud handles plugins being click-to-play.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer edited 2013.03.15 to improve accuracy of information**

A list of supported plugins is available as an array in the `navigator` object:

```
navigator.plugins
```

This API is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.plugins#Specification), but all modern browsers implement it. Internet Explorer support goes back to at least IE7, but it's not available in old versions of Opera.

`navigator.plugins` has this basic structure:

```
PluginArray [
    ...
    Plugin {
        description: "Java Plug-In 2 for NPAPI Browsers"
        filename: "JavaAppletPlugin.plugin"
        length: 17
        name: "Java Plug-In 2 for NPAPI Browsers"
    },
    ...
]
```

Here's a function that loops over `navigator.plugins` and checks the `name` property for a given string. It returns `true` or `false` if found.

```
function pluginEnabled(name) {
    var plugins = navigator.plugins,
        i = plugins.length,
        regExp = new RegExp(name, 'i');
    while (i--) {
        if (regExp.test(plugins[i].name)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use it like so (case insensitive):

```
pluginEnabled('java');
pluginEnabled('flash');
```

Comment: Checking `navigator.plugins` only tells you if a plugin is installed or not. It may still fail to load, get blocked or made click-to-play, and those conditions can't be found out via a content-accessible API.